Show the report generated with FastReport on React.js without iframe
I create reports with FastReport on the .NET Core WEB API side. I want to show these reports on our website using react.js. I normally convert the generated report to ByteArray and show it with a PdfViewer library on the React side. However, now I need to use the features provided by FastReport such as export, zoom, etc. Is it possible to do this without returning a view from the WEB API and without using iframes?
